# определить сколько четных и нечетных чисел без if и циклов

Tags: c++

есть какое то n от 1 до 10

как определить для n сколько в нем четных и нечетных не включая последнее?

четные. n = 8 ---> 2,4,6 --> 3 четных

нечетные. n = 8 ---> 1,3,5,7 --> 4 нечетных

n = 3 --> одно четное 2

n = 3 --> одно нечетное 1

Comment: Что означает у вас «в нём»? Число — это не множество.

Comment: "в нем" означает в его диапозоне от 1 до n

Comment: ну тогда (r-l)/2 ну там +- 1 добавить.

Comment: (n-1)/2 `even`
n/2 `odd`

Answer (score 6):

`(n-1)/2` четных
`n/2` нечетных

Деление целочисленное

Comment: ох, как же я невнимателен. изначально так и написал, но не уследил за порядком и написал n-1/2